# How can I prevent my keyup function to be one character delayed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, keyup, wysihtml5

I have a `textarea`, and when I write something, then the text should appear in my `result`box in the same moment.

I am using a `keyup` function and also tested `keydown`. But my problem is, that the insert is one character delayed. Or if I write fast it can be more characters.

So for example I write

`abcdf`

into my `textarea` and in my `result` box the result is

`abcd`

If I add another character, for example `z` then the `f` is appearing.

```
$(document).off("click", ".button").on("click", ".button", function (event) {
  $.ajax({
     url: "update.php",
        data: {
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.textarea').wysihtml5({
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var some_wysi = $('.textarea').data('wysihtml5').editor;
                        $(some_wysi.composer.element).bind('keyup', function(){ 
                         var text = $( ".textarea").val();
                            $(".box[data-select='true']").find($('.result')).val(text);
                        }
                     }
                }
            })
         }
     })
  }

<button class="button">button</button>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="box" data-select="true"><div class="result"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when watching for changes to fields with user input, keyboard events are not the right thing to watch for. Consider the case where the user right-clicks the field and chooses "paste" from the context menu. There's also the issue of the order in which the events occur relative to updating the field's value.

Instead, use the `input` event, or (in your specific case) whatever "the value changed" event your WYSIWYG editor provides (which might be `change` or something else).

---

If none of the documented events works, a **very imperfect** solution might be to delay your update by one event loop cycle via `setTimeout`.

```
// A flag so we don't schedule timer callbacks repeatedly
var timerPending = false;

// Our callback function
function handleUpdate() {
    timerPending = false;
    var text = $( ".textarea").val();
    $(".box[data-select='true']").find($('.result')).val(text);
}

// Hook a bunch of events to try to get as broad a set of notifications as possible
$(some_wysi.composer.element).bind('keydown keyup keypress input change', function() { 
    // Since we're hooking multiple events, we may get multiple notifications
    // within the same event loop; only setup a timer callback for the first one
    if (!timerPending) {
        timerPending = true;
        setTimeout(handleUpdate, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested input or change event. But this is not working unfortunately.

Comment: @Jarla: Well, again, I would refer to the plugin's documentation for what event or mechanism it gives you to know when the value changes.

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. And the events are working for their purpose. But there is no event like keyup that is fireing in the moment you are writing

Comment: @Jarla: I've suggested a workaround in the answer. May be worth opening an issue with the plugin vendor for a proactive notification event.

Comment: Thank you, this is nice. I tested your solution. Just changed `setTimeout(handleUpdate, 0);` to `setTimeout(handleUpdate, 1500);` It is working for now. If  I find a better solution, I will post it here